# Unable to get json to listview working

Tags: java, android, json, string, parsing

I already have PHP to pull the info from MySQL and encode to json, example output below:

```
[{"name":"Player A","score":1459},{"name":"Player B","score":1434}]
```

I'm struggling to follow guides where I can parse this into a listview. For a start, it seems massively overcomplicated, needing custom adapters, large custom classes defining everything etc

Am I being naive thinking there should be an easy way to read this data from a URL and assign to a listview? I only need name and score fields for a basic scoreboard.

Even if I could just split the entire output up into strings, this would be more than enough as I could then do textview.setText(string1) and so on ...

If anyone has a working example of pulling json from a URL and being able to either pass this to a listview, or if its simpler, to be able to pass the output to strings?

Comment: read json string using Gson & make model class of your json string  ,set Arraylist of that model class to your Custome List's Adpter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use RecyclerView for parsing the json data.This link is the most simplest way to parse the json data.
http://androidcss.com/android/fetch-json-data-android/
Try it :)

Comment: @user9739950 First you try with this.This is the native method.If you want the newest method you can use Retrofit.

Comment: I did get this partly working, but it was scrolling the entire screen for each item, and duplicating a background each time also. I played with this for several hours before giving up and trying something else.

Comment: This link is working perfectly.The reason for scrolling each item in entire screen is  design problem of item xml.Give specefic height for the widgets in xml :)

Comment: I long deleted it after I couldn't get it working - I tried editing the layout height, putting it inside a nested layout and limited the height of that, all that did was still scroll the whole thing one item per page, but in a smaller window. Also this still seems like a lot of extra things for something that I expected would be much easier.

Comment: OK I went through this again and adapted it to fit my code etc, but now I have one list item per screen again, so it needs a full scroll just to show each "Name   Score" - how do I keep them to one screen? I only aim to pull 10 items each time so these would easily fit

Comment: My fault - I had a background image in the xml for the recycler rather than the container

Answer (score 0):

Create a class **SimpleModel.java**

```
public class SimpleModel {


    private int score;
    private String name;

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and parse it using `Gson` like this

```
    String YOUR_RESPOSE_STRING = "";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type lisType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<SimpleModel>>() {
    }.getType();
    ArrayList<SimpleModel> list = gson.fromJson(YOUR_RESPOSE_STRING, lisType);
```

Comment: Where would the call to the URL be added here please?

Comment: for url call you have to use volley , Retrofit  and get the response from url . this answer i have given for to parse the json array after reeving the response